# Transformer drawing 29x more current than it needs

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, energy, efficiency

I have an old transformer (20+ yrs) in a building I manage (GE Model 9T23B3872), it takes 277V 3-phase and converts it to 120V 3-phase.  It seems very wasteful.  It is drawing a combined 8.7 A @ 277 V or 2409.9 W from the breakers that feed it, but it only needs to be drawing 0.7 A @ 120 V or 84 W (the total current being drawn by all 120v lines in the breaker box that it feeds).  How can there be such a discrepancy between the load on the transformer and the current that the transformer is drawing?  There's almost a 29-fold difference here!  Is this par for the course in terms of transformers?

Comment: It seems to be working the opposite of what it should be. It should only be drawing about 35 watts off the 277 lines. Sounds like a winding has shorted. They are not repairable as they are sealed in epoxy resin. Disconnect from power and test the primary wires with an ohm meter. All phases should read the same. If a phase reads a bit or a lot lower than the others, there's your shorted winding.

Comment: That's a 30kVA transformer, there's going to be some power loss from just plugging it in.

Comment: http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/9T23B3872-LBL?TNR=Drawings-Outline%20and%20Dimensional%7C9T23B3872-LBL%7CPDF&filename=9T23B3872-LBL.pdf

Comment: Is it taking 2.5kW of 'getting hot' power, or is this magnetising current, that has to flow for making such a large transformer work, but doesn't heat the transformer, and you don't get charged for by your supplier either, as it's VAr, not watts?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably just magnetising current

that transformer is after-all **300 times bigger than it needs to be** to satisfy an 84 VA load

https://buy.wesco.com/General-Purpose-Multi-Use/GENERAL-ELECTRIC/General-Purpose-Transformer-60Hz-3-Ph-30-KVA/9T23B3872/p/78317300492-1

Oh, you can't multiply AC amps by volts and get watts,  what you get is VA. watts will be less, you need to use a wattmeter to measure watts.

Magnetising current it the current that flows in the transformer primary according to it's inductance

Answer (score 0):

First, that thing you call "277V 3-phase" is actually called 480V 3-phase wye.   It's 480V phase to phase  to phase (corners), and 277V phase to neutral (center).

The transformer outputs 208 3-phase wye, which is set up so phase to neutral is good old familiar 120V.

I would look at which phases on the primary are flowing how much current, as well as the neutral.  If it is lopsided, then also measure the secondary the same way.   Is that imbalance going into the panel like that?  If you turn off everything in the panel, does the transformer load go away?

How hot does the transformer get?

Normal transformer losses are on the order of 2-3 percent.